# Stack corruption upon calling OpenSSL DES_cbc_encrypt()

Tags: c, openssl, des, stack-corruption

This is code to encrypt a `struct` using `DES` and then read it back after writing to `File` :

```
#include "openssl/des.h"
#include "openssl/conf.h"
#include "openssl/evp.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct MyStruct_t
{
        char m_Name[32];
        char m_ID[16];
} MyStruct;


uint8_t* __stdcall myStructToBytes(const MyStruct * const iMyStruct)
{
    const size_t len = sizeof(MyStruct;
    uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t*) malloc(len);

    memcpy(buffer, iMyStruct, len);
    return buffer;
}

const int __stdcall encodeMyStructToFile(const char *sOutputFilename,
                                                         const char *sKey, const MyStruct *iStruct)
{
    DES_cblock key, iv;
    DES_key_schedule schedule;
    unsigned char *data = myStructToBytes((const MyStruct * const)iStruct);
    long len = sizeof(MyStruct);
    int ret = 0;

    memcpy(key, &sKey[0], 8);
    memcpy(iv, &sKey[0], 8);
    DES_set_odd_parity(&key);
    ret = DES_set_key_checked(&key, &schedule);

    if(ret == 0) {
        FILE *write_ptr;
        unsigned char *encrypted = (unsigned char *)malloc(len);
        DES_cbc_encrypt(data, encrypted, len, &schedule, &iv, DES_ENCRYPT);

        // Write encrypted data to file...
        fopen_s(&write_ptr, sOutputFilename, "wb");
        fwrite(encrypted, len, 1, write_ptr);
        fclose(write_ptr);
        free(encrypted);
    }
    free(data);

    return ret;
}


const int __stdcall decodeMyStructFromFile(const char *sInputFilename,
           const char *sKey, MyStruct *oStruct)
{
    int ret = 0;
    DES_cblock key, iv;
    DES_key_schedule schedule;
    FILE *read_ptr;
    long len = 0;
    unsigned char *encrypted = NULL;

    // Read encrypted data from file...
    fopen_s(&read_ptr, sInputFilename, "rb");
    ret = fseek(read_ptr, 0L, SEEK_END);
    len = ftell(read_ptr);
    rewind(read_ptr);
    encrypted = (unsigned char *)malloc(len);
    fread(encrypted, len, 1, read_ptr);
    fclose(read_ptr);

    // Perform decryption...
    memcpy(key, &sKey[0], 8);
    memcpy(iv, &sKey[0], 8);
    DES_set_odd_parity(&key);
    ret = DES_set_key_checked(&key, &schedule);

    if(ret == 0) {
        DES_cbc_encrypt(encrypted, (unsigned char *)oStruct, len, &schedule, &iv, DES_DECRYPT);
    }
    free(encrypted);

    return ret;
}

int main() {
    MyStruct tMyStruct;
    MyStruct tMyStruct1;
    char outputFilename[] = "abcd.bin";
    char key[] = "key_to_file";

    memset(&tMyStruct, 0, sizeof(MyStruct));
    memcpy_s(tMyStruct.m_Name, 256, "Hello", 5);
    memcpy_s(tMyStruct.m_ID, 32, "1234567890", 10);

    encodeMyStructToFile((const char *)outputFilename, (const char *)key, (const MyStruct * const)&tMyStruct);

    decodeLicenseStructFromFile(outputFilename, key, &tMyStruct1);


    return 0;
}
```

Somehow, I get stack corruption error in debugger for both encrypt and decrypt functions. I traced down the problem around `DES_cbc_encrypt()`. What am I doing wrong? I'm using compiled binaries for OpenSSL: `openssl-1.1.0e-vs2012` on `64-bit`.

Comment: `memcpy_s(tMyStruct.m_Name, 256, "Hello", 5);` --> `memcpy_s(tMyStruct.m_Name, 32, "Hello", 5);` and `memcpy_s(tMyStruct.m_ID, 32, "1234567890", 10);` --> `memcpy_s(tMyStruct.m_ID, 16, "1234567890", 10);`

Comment: I'm so silly! Thanks!:)

Comment: Best using `sizeof(tMyStruct.m_Name)` and `sizeof(tMyStruct.m_ID)`

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance. Is this still a problem?

Comment: **Do not use DES** in new work, it is not secure and has been superseded by AES (Advanced Encryption Standard. AES is a similar block based encryption that is not harder to use but is secure.

Comment: The IV must be unpredictable (read: random). Don't use a static IV or an IV based on the key, because that makes the cipher deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. An attacker who observes ciphertexts can determine when the same message prefix was sent before. The IV is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the direct weakness around static IV. I do not have much understanding about cryptographic ciphers. Adding the IV as prefix, seems good idea. I would read more about AES and vulnerabilities around DES, as zaph mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason, why I came back here, is because I noticed (although not producible from the sample code), that both `DES_cbc_encrypt()` and `DES_cbc_decrypt()` functions expect `8-byte aligned` inputs. Thus in the unfortunate case, if the struct here would have been not a multiple of 8 in size, `DES_cbc_encrypt()` would write past the end of buffer, thus the obvious stack-corruption. Although, when padding is not explicitly disabled, `sizeof()` still returns the sum of the sizes of the members, so this case I understand is the task of the application programmer. Maybe someone could light up more on this.